# Magento: Add items to new order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

So, here is my problem:
If a customer places a new order and he/she has an existing pending order with a backordered item, the two orders must merge. So I created an observer at the `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` event. The idea was that in this observer I check the email of the customer and check if he/she has an existing pending order. If such order exist I put the items of the old order in the new one and delete/cancel the old order. Here is my function:

```
public function salesQuoteSubmitBefore($observer){
$customerEmail = $observer->getQuote()->getData('customer_email');
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore());
    $customer->loadByEmail($customerEmail);

    $oldOrder = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => array('new')))
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending')))
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
    ->setPageSize(1);
    $oldID = $oldOrder->getData();

    if($oldID[0]['increment_id'] != '' && $oldID[0]['increment_id'] > 0){
        $mergeOrder = false;
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($oldID[0]['increment_id']);
        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
            if($product->getStockItem()->getQty() < 0){
                $mergeOrder = true; 
            }   
        }

        if($mergeOrder){
            $newOrder = $observer->getOrder();
            $quote = $newOrder->getQuote();

            $tmp = array();
            foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
                $tmp[] = $item->getSku();
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
                $qty = array('qty'=>$item->getQty());
                $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_object($qty));
            }

            foreach($quote->getAllAddresses() as $a){
                $a->unsetData('cached_items_nonnominal');
                $a->unsetData('cached_items_nominal');
            }

            $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
            $quote->save();

            $newOrder->setQuote($quote)->save();
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)->save();
            //Mage::throwException('obs: '.json_encode($newOrder->getQuote()->getData()));
        }
    }
}
```

The Mage:throwExeption prints the new quote and all is right, quantity, totals... and if I print the newOrder all is right too! but when the order is placed the old data is used, so the new order is without the old items.

What or where to save the changed order/quote so the new data is used for the order creation? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding product in quote, try adding in cart. Like below

```
$cart =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProduct($product, array('qty'=>$qty)); 
$cart->save();
```

Comment: Tried, but with the same result. Maybe I have the wrong event, because when the exception is thrown the order is not placed and in the cart there are the products from the previous order.

Comment: After some research in my shop, I found that a module is overriding the normal saveOrder function and same events are not triggered. When found the new saveOrder function, I created a new event and with some modification of the function now works. Thank you anyway :)